# How does Case work in an impersonal sentence?

Tags: syntax, verbs, cases, x-bar-theory, clauses

The **Case filter** is what prohibits the phonetic realization of a DP that recieves no grammatical Case. In languages such as Portuguese, people use impersonal constructions like *"há/tem um carro na rua"*, meaning "there is a car in the street". The verb *"haver"* (and *"ter"*, nowadays) is impersonal, so the subject is always expletive and null in this language (which is pro-drop).

The problem is: how does the DP "um carro" get its Case to pass the Case filter? It doesn't seem to be receiving accusative Case by the verb, I guess. **What is happening in this kind of construction?**

Comment: Wouldn't it get its case in the same way as "this vehicle **is a car**"? Or is there a reason it has to be analyzed differently?

Comment: Why wouldn’t it be receiving accusative Case by the verb? When replaced by a pronoun, the objective (≈accusative) form is used: “Há carros na rua?” — “Não, não _os_ há”. This matches non-impersonal uses of _haver_ and _ter_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet , I'm a portuguese native speaker and I've never seen a phrase like "não os há", it doesn't work at all

Comment: @Draconis , it is not a copula verb, I don't see why should it work the same way

Comment: @ErgativeMan It’s certainly rare, but I did find some examples of it in use, such as [“Método milagroso de gramática! Não o há!”](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tr3y_POZlC0) on YouTube. It’s not like in Spanish where _no lo hay_ is fairly commonplace, but it doesn’t appear to be entirely absent either in actual usage. At least in Brazilian Portuguese – from a quick scan, none of the examples seemed definitely to be European.

Comment: @ErgativeMan "não os há" does work... E.g: *"Precisávamos **dos** (pregos e dos martelos) mas, não **os** há"*. Fairly common in European Portuguese... If its use is uncommon in Brazilian Portuguese it's likely because of the dialect specific phonetic strangeness caused by the last diacritic of the three monosyllable sequence.

Comment: In Brazilian Portuguese direct object pronouns are often replaced by subject pronouns: Eu **o** vi. ( saw him) becomes: Eu vi **ele**. where ele is he, not him.  The higher  up the social ladder you go, the more you might be likely to hear Eu o vi na rua. [I saw him in the street].  And Há carros na rua? would most like be answered as: Sim,  sim, há. But **more commonly you'd hear**: Tem carros na rua? Response: Sim, tem. No pronoun at all in fact. Iberian Portuguese uses direct object pronouns much more frequently.